# Button action not working in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an IPhone application in which i am adding a custom view inspite of a navigation bar view.i am hiding that custom view in the normal case and unhide it whenever needed.now i am adding a button to that custom view having an action .but when i am clicking on it there is no action is working.can anybody help me?here is my code snippet in the view didload`

```
curtainsView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
curtainsView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"curtains.png"];
curtainsView.frame=CGRectMake(0,-44, 320, 60);
curtainsView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
UIImage *button2Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scroll_down.png"];
scroll = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
self.scroll.tag=100;
[scroll setImage:button2Image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.scroll.frame = CGRectMake(270,0, 40,40);
[scroll addTarget:self action:@selector(backpressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[self.curtainsView addSubview:scroll];
[self.view addSubview:curtainsView];
[self changeNavigationBarTitleTo:@""];
[curtainsView setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Can you verify with logs that `backpressed:` is being called?

Comment: Does using `scroll = [[UIButton alloc] init];` instead of `scroll = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];` help?

Comment: where do you add this button to, exactly?

Comment: adding that button to the subview named curtainsview

Comment: Look at @omk answer. It seems to be correct. `UIImageView` by default disables the user interaction with it and its subviews

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable user interaction of curtainsView.

Try this:

```
[curtainsView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]
```

From Apple's [UIImageView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> New image view objects are configured to disregard user events by default. If you want to handle events in a custom subclass of UIImageView, you must explicitly change the value of the userInteractionEnabled property to YES after initializing the object.

Answer (score 0):

Check the signature of the `backPressed` method. I tripped up at first not realizing that `@selector(backpressed:)` looks for:

```
-(void)backPressed:(id)sender { // the colon indicates the first argument
```

If your signature does not have a sender argument, you will either need to add one or drop the colon in the `@selector`. Ie:

```
-(void)backPressed
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about your whole code why you are hiding the view but what i want to say that add your `UIButton` to your `self.view` instead of `self.curtainsView`.

Just make a little change in your code.

```
[self.view addSubview:curtainsView];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

Comment: i want that button to be on the curtainsview

Comment: Your button action is working fine i'm sure you can see just put a break point here, but you cant navigate your self.view from here.

Answer (score 0):

Enable user interaction of curtainsView.

```
[curtainsView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]
```