# actions on UIButton when it's added to UIImageView is not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Button action not working in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264519/button-action-not-working-in-iphone)

I have an application in which instead of navigation bars view I am adding an image view. Like this in the view did load method.

```
curtainsView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];

curtainsView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"curtains.png"];
curtainsView.frame=CGRectMake(0,-44, 320, 60);
curtainsView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

[self.view addSubview:curtainsView];
```

Now I want to add a button on to that image view.i am trying to achieve that with this

```
UIImage *button2Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scroll_down.png"];
UIButton *scroll = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//scroll = [[UIButton alloc] init];
//self.scroll.tag=100;
[scroll setImage:button2Image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
scroll.frame = CGRectMake(270,-30, 40,40);
[scroll addTarget:self action:@selector(backpressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
//[scroll setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

not working. Then I tried this also

```
UIButton *btnDetail = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]retain];

btnDetail.frame = CGRectMake(260,-15,100,100);
[btnDetail addTarget:self action:@selector(backpressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];

[self.curtainsView addSubview:btnDetail];
[self.curtainsView bringSubviewToFront:btnDetail];
[self.curtainsView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

also not working. If it is in side that image view it is not working, but when I tried to add the second code with frame `CGRectMake(260,0,100,100)` its working. But I need that button to be inside that image view. Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Just check that ur btnPress event is calling or not

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/q/12264519/310903

Answer (score 1):

You should not add a subview on imageViews.
Instead add your button to self.view above your imageView.
And don't add you button outside of its superview bounds.

```
UIImage *button2Image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scroll_down.png"];
UIButton *scroll = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[scroll setImage:button2Image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
scroll.frame = CGRectMake(270, 0, 40, 40);
[scroll addTarget:self action:@selector(backpressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

Comment: that also i tried.first one .not working

Comment: Not working because your button is out of the frame of its superview. (scroll.frame = CGRectMake(270,-30, 40,40);)

Comment: then how can i add to that imageview.?

Comment: Like i said, add your button on the imageView's superview, above the imageView, and set it frame so that it is inside its superview bounds. For that, maybe you can increase the superview's frame.

Comment: it will be great if u edit ur answer with the code.i am not getting u properly?

Comment: sorry.that wont bring the button on the desired position that i want?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
UIImageView *imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 300)];
imgview.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
imgview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:imgview];


UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.Frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20);
btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickActonOfButtons) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[imgview addSubview:btn];
btn=nil;
[imgview release];
```

Note: if you will add a image on button... In this case 
`imgview.userInteractionEnabled=NO;`

Answer (score 0):

make your ImgView's userInteractionEnabled to YES as default is NO.

the touch in UIImageView is not passed to UIButton.

```
curtainsView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

Also set UIButton's userInteractionEnabled to YES

```
btnDetail.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

Also check btnDetail's bound is outside of superviews bounds  when setting frame like CGRectMake(260,-15,100,100);

When u set CGRectMake(260,0,100,100) it works because btnDetail's bound is in visble area and inside the superviews bounds

Comment: As curtainsView is superview of UIButton. By default UIImageView's userInteractionEnabled is NO and it will be visible. So u cannot touch button until IImageView's userInteractionEnabled is YES

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a button on a view not on image view.
Add your button to a self.view instead of imageview.

```
    [self.view addSubview:btnDetail];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnDetail];
```

It will work fine.